# Trying to get Google Plus comments for an activity

Tags: ruby, rest, google-plus

I've been trying to use the Google Plus API (how they managed to make this difficult is beyond me), and I'm trying to get all of a user's comments (or at least the most recent ones).

Unfortunately, Google has decided to make this inaccessible through one call, so I've been trying to access all of a user's activities, and the list of comments for each. To do this, I've been using the [google_plus](https://github.com/seejohnrun/google_plus/) gem.

I can pull up a user, no problem. However, for each user I pull up, their activities seem to be `nil`. Moreover, if I try to fetch an activity by id, that also returns `nil`. For example, I've tried to hit [this activity](https://plus.google.com/107200121064812799857/posts/GkyGQPLi6KD) using an id of 107200121064812799857, but I get nothing.

I've even tried using [Google's API testing tool to try](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/comments/list) to hit this activity (using the aforementioned ID), and *it* can't even seem to find it.

Can someone explain what's going on here? Maybe I'm not using the right ID, or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've even tried using Google's API testing tool to try to hit this activity (using the aforementioned ID)
>   The comments.list API requires an activity id, but you're passing the Google+ profile id.

You will need to pass a valid activity id when using the comments.list api.

For this post on Google+: https://plus.google.com/107200121064812799857/posts/GkyGQPLi6KD

- The user id is: 107200121064812799857
- The activity id (used by the API) is: z13qd5zouuebcpauy23tuftwdsylxflvs

Here's how you can list comments for that activity id:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.comments.list?activityId=z13qd5zouuebcpauy23tuftwdsylxflvs&alt=json

Comment: How did you get the activity id?

Comment: Nevermind. W/r/t the answer to my original question, I got it by doing Activities => list and then for each of those, Activity => comments.